# Query in DB2 vs Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, view, db2

There is a query having multiple inner joins. It involves two views, of which one view is based on four tables,  and total there are four tables(including two views).

The same query with the same amount of data in the source tables runs in both, Oracle and DB2. In DB2, surprisingly, it takes 2 minutes to load 3 million records. While in Oracle, it is taking two hours. Same indexes are on all source tables in both the environments. Is the behavior of views (when used in joins) different in both environments (Oracle vs DB2)?

a dummy query I am sharing :-

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE_A
 SELECT
        adf.column1,
        adf.column2,
        dd.column3,
        SUM(otl.column4) column4,
        SUM(otl.column5) column5,
        (Case when SUM(otl.column5) = 0 then 0
        else round(CAST(SUM(otl.column4) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) /abs(CAST(SUM(otl.column4) AS DECIMAL(18,2))),4)
        end) taxl_unrlz_cgl_pct
 FROM
        view_a adf
        INNER JOIN table_b hr on hr.hh_ref_id = adf.hh_ref_id
              AND  hr.col_typ_cd = 'FIRM'
              AND  hr.col_end_dt =  TO_DATE('1/1/2900','MM/DD/YYYY')
        INNER JOIN dw.table_c ar on ar.colb_id = adf.colb_id
              AND  ar.col_cd = '@'
              AND  ar.col_num BETWEEN 10000000 AND 89999999
              AND  ar.col_dt IS NULL
        INNER JOIN table_d dd on dd.col_id = adf.col_id
        INNER JOIN view2 otl ON otl.cola_id = ar.cola_id
 GROUP BY adf.column1, adf.column2, dd.column3;
```

Comment: And how can i optimise this...i can't share the query due to confidential constraints....

Comment: If you can't share the query, the least you can do is to compare the access plans from both RDBMSs.  Looks like something is awry with the Oracle plan and most likely it can be easily corrected by examination of the access-plan.  If the hardware-resources are similar and table layouts similar (you did not mention either of these) then there's no reason why Oracle performance would be worse than that of Db2 other than misconfiguration.

Comment: @PrithuBarnwal You can change table names and column names to make it non-confidential.

Comment: A dummy query i am giving...u can get an idea

Comment: @mao hardware resources are same...only differnece is that in DB2,direct table has been used instead of the view(but that sld not affect any performance) for one of the views

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan for that query. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Did you try using same SQL in both places and comparing the performance? One of your comments suggests that different sqls were used.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, both DB2 and Oracle will try to rewrite the query in most efficient way possible using the base query that you have coded. But one of the common (but not frequent) issues that I have seen when using multi-table view is DBMS not being able to rewrite the query using underlying tables. So depending on complexity of the view itself and sometime the additional joins, DBMS may not be able to rewrite the query to use the underlying tables properly and hence resulting in not being able to use the indexes on the underlying tables used in the view. When this happens, the view itself acts like a materialized table (work table) and query goes for table scan on the materialized table.

There is no consistent pattern on when such issue can happen. So you will need to check on a case by case basis.

Since you are mentioning about 2 hrs vs 2 minutes, in most probability that might be the case. So you will need to check the access path on both Oracle and DB2. But you will also need to make sure that stats are updated and access path is based on latest stats on DBMS. Else it won't be apples to apples compare.